# How execute a controller in a sub-folder using a URL in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

How can I execute a controller i a sub-folder using a URL in Codeigniter?

If I have the next controllers y controllers folder:

```
-/controllers/
      |---------controller1.php
      |---------/sub-folder/
                     |---------controller2.php
```

I can execute `controller1.php` using a URL similar to this:
`example.com/index.php/controller1/function/param`

But, How can I execute `controller2.php`?

Very important:

=> make sure your sub folder name is not any of the controller's name

**=> make sure your class name and file name is same****

Comment: Did you try `example.com/index.php/sub-folder/controller2/function/param` ? I think codeigniter will allow you to do this up to 1 level of subfolders.

Comment: @Jeemusu. That doesn't work. My mistake. I forgot to include in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
 example.com/index.php/sub-folder/controller2/function/param
```

**=> make sure your sub folder name is not any of the controller's name**

**=> make sure your class name and file name is same**

Comment: That doesn't work. My mistake. I forgot to include in question.

Comment: 404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Comment: check your controller name, make sure the file name and the class name is same

Answer (score 1):

You can execute,

```
example.com/index.php/sub-folder/controller2/function/param
```